# What does 'scaled' in 'scaled point' mean?

Tags: meaning

As a non-English speaker, I'm confused with it when I want to translate the term `scaled point`: A scaled point is of fixed size. It could not be scaled up or down. Why it is called a **scaled** point?

Comment: Please, show an example using this term.

Comment: @Sigur It is almost sure that OP has in mind 65536 sp = 1 pt.

Comment: It can't be scaled up or down, because it has been already *scaled*. May be you think it means *scalable point*? Hece it not being scalable, but fixed, disorients you.

Comment: @sigur: 7 matches for "scaled point" in buffer: texbook.tex
   3317:sp&scaled point ($\rm65536\,sp=1\,pt$)\cr}$$
   3326:^^|sp|^^{scaled point}
   7199:of~^{sp} (scaled points).
   7213:of~sp (scaled points). For example, if\/ |\skip1| holds the value
  16767:integer by assuming units of scaled points. For example, if\/ |\hsize=100pt|
  27542:scaled points, 57--58, 270.
  27640:|sp| (scaled point), +57, 118--119, 270, 398, 400.
:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks. Very technical, as always.

Comment: Just to augment what's been said so far, since you mention you're not a (native) English speaker: in the context of scaled points, the word "scaled" is used as the past tense form (and/or perfect tense form) of the verb "to scale". A scaled point (`sp`) is a unit of length that's obtained by multiplying a (North American) typographic point (`pt`) by `2^{-16}=1/65536`. Since the multiplicative factor is between 0 and 1 (and rather closer to 0 than it is to 1!), this multiplicative operation may quite naturally be called a "scaling (down)" of the length unit `pt`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

well it's just a name, but (presumably) it refers to the fact that it's 1/2^{16} pt so it is essentially pt but scaled by 2^{16} so that TeX can use integer arithmetic to manipulate fractional pt dimensions.